# How can I find the name of a bill mentioned in the press?

Tags: united-states, law, donald-trump, abortion

Recently I have read a lot of news stories saying that President Trump is working on a religious freedom law which could allow doctors to refuse to do abortions or treat transgender patients.

However, I can’t seem to find the name of this bill/proposed bill, any actual quotes from it, or any recent quotes from President Trump about this topic.

How can I find first-hand information like this?

Edit: One article talking about the topic is “Trump Gives Health Workers New Religious Liberty Protections,” posted yesterday by the New York Times.

Comment: Looks like it's all hot air for now.

Comment: Note that when someone says they are "working on a bill" said "bill" might be nothing yet but a word document on their team's private network share.

Comment: @Philipp - or that they held a meeting to discuss establishing a committee to appoint a working group. No i'm not bitter after a workday full of meetings, why did you ask?

Comment: Could you show some of these articles?  Keep in mind, most reputable news sources will link to the bill somewhere in the article (or a source article that they based their info off of).  If they do not have these, then chances are it's not a very reliable source.

Comment: Per the cited article, the freedom is based on the procedure, not the identity of the patient.  This question has made up an entirely different and misleading wording of the claim, presumably to make it more incendiary.

Comment: @Ben Voigt What question? My question? I’m not trying to be misleading or make anything incendiary; I’m just looking for more information... Who is making things incendiary? :(

Comment: .... Unless he's looking to make changes via executive order and administrative discretion, which was the impression I got from similar stories, in which case you won't find any record of proposed legislation. I think he's ordering a new unit/division to be formed within the Department of Health and Human Services where they will be tasked with helping to defend people who want to go that route. Whether he has the authority to create these kinds of functions where they are not defined or authorized via legislation, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

The [Library of Congress](https://www.congress.gov) has an excellent resource to do just that.

<del>For your specific question, searching “religious freedom” in the Search Box will give you the bill you’re looking for: S. 1114 (the second result on the page).</del>

Note that Trump can also govern via Executive Orders — which is what happened in this case. These won’t be covered by the Library of Congress [website](https://www.congress.gov).

Comment: +1 for excellent quality of answer. -1 because the bill you found seems to be 100% opposite of what the OP asked (It's Feinstein's bill to counter Trump, not Trump's notional bill :)

Comment: I don’t think this is quite the right bill. S. 1114 attempts to nullify an executive order Trump made in May of 2017. I’m looking for the bill mentioned in an article the New York Times published yesterday. The article is called, “Trump Gives Health Workers New Religious Liberty Protections”.

Comment: Yep, my bad, I just skimmed the Bill’s Summary :)

Comment: THe President cannot govern via executive order, at least not legally.  Executive orders are only to point law enforcement at existing laws. Granted, there are many examples in the previous administrations where law has been created by executive order, but not within the spirit, or law of the Constitution

Comment: @FrankCedeno sorta, but when congress writes more than a few laws with something like "... and that agency will be empowered to make and enforce rules to that effect" in it chances are an executive order can do something similar to anything the president wants.

Answer (score 2):

The president has no official role in legislation, other than signing or vetoing bills. For proposed legislation to be a "bill", it has to be proposed by members of congress, which is generally done through committees. The president can make suggestions to congress as to what bills to introduce, but that does not carry any official legal weight. So if Trump is "working" on a bill, there is no official bill, and thus no official bill name, until congress acts. Until that happens, there will be no official records, and this comes down to how to search for any other alleged plans of Trump: perhaps he's tweeted about, maybe he's mentioned it in a speech, maybe he's brought it up in a meeting.

An executive order would be a different matter.